# php "for loop" with time interval

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I want to find a way to execute increment for every 5 mins, please help

```
example
for ($i=1;$i<=11;$i++) {
echo $i;
}
```

print

1. after 5min
2. after 5min
3. after 5min
4. after 5min
5. after 5min 
   ......

Comment: The wisdom of doing this is somewhat questionable. Can you tell us why you want to delay execution? Honestly, this sounds like more of a job for a scheduler (see the reference to cron below) than for a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i=1;$i<=11;$i++) {
sleep(300);
echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`sleep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Or, do you want a cron job?

Comment: @will.i.am `sleep(300)` will hold execution for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a script every 5 minutes, you should use a cronjob. If you are using a control panel such as cPanel or DirectAdmin you can add the cronjob. If you have (only) SSH access to the machine then use the `crontab -e` command and add the following line:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /location/of/the/script.php
```

If you `/usr/bin/php`is not your PHP path, then create a script and use `<?php phpinfo();` to find out what the location actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cron Jobs or Sleep Function in php

if the cron jobs is disable on your server than use free online cron jobs service

http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/